# Target two fields when searching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this layout:

```
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello</div>
  <div class="description">lorem</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">ipsum</div>
  <div class="description">test</div>
</div>
```

And I allow users to search the `entry` divs **by** the content of the `title` div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#search").on("keyup click input", function () {
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        if (val.length) {
            jQuery(".entry").hide().filter(function () {
                return jQuery('.title',this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            }).show();
        }
        else {
            jQuery(".entry").show();
        }
    });

});
```

Works great. Try [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rc5vfx30/1/).

My question is, how do I make it so the search targets both the content of the `title` div **and** the `description` field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to search for both `title` and `description` use this.

```
return jQuery('.title, .description',this)
```

Then it will look like

```
jQuery(".entry").hide().filter(function () {
    return jQuery('.title, .description',this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}).show();
```

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nj50a0gq/) so you can test it.

Answer (score 3):

In the filter function, you can add an OR condition that can check the description and filter results on title or description.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#search").on("keyup click input", function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    if (val.length) {
      jQuery(".entry").hide().filter(function() {
        return jQuery('.title, .description', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      }).show();
    } else {
      jQuery(".entry").show();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.entry {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello</div>
  <div class="description">lorem</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">ipsum</div>
  <div class="description">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Check if this is what you are looking for:` is not a good answer - at least describe what you've changed! Particularly as the bit you have changed is scrolled out of view.

Comment: Sure. Apologies for that. I wasn't completely sure, hence I asked "looking for"

Comment: Then you maybe wanted to comment rather than answer (if seeking clarification of what the OP wanted)

Comment: Got it @Jamiec. Will take care next time. :)